# Use nth-child() on data-ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

im trying to change the image of a data-ng-repeat function witch i don't have full access. I have try the nth-child() method but is only showing me the first image on all repeats. i have 9 repeated values but on all 9 it shows the same image, hope you can help me. thanks

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLxi2.png)

```css
.imgforcat img:nth-child(1) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955412/vjdipw4kr8vkxb0mtgzu.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(2) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955414/ybytihuolboqyipaomth.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(3) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955417/wcurk4xxzkuhkcb4kfyk.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(4) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955420/qzqsnfu16ksmgciczp0i.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(5) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955423/i89yd4gygnfobtkt5sst.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(6) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955426/bibll3zypbxobjvqwa7i.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(7) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955429/mabhmve6oamdpanpw7vj.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(8) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955433/jrjzziz0ytkzbg5zgsiu.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(9) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955436/xrwinousjczidyswesls.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(10) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955439/bnrvfukc9fcj2ii8vjkt.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
.imgforcat img:nth-child(11) {background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ordering2/image/upload/v1613955442/x6qsfdkndd57v6ihhkqk.png");height: 74px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;position: relative;width: 74px;border-radius: 17px;border: 0 !important;box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px #76848e6b;}
```

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="btypes in allbusinesstypes | orderBy:'id*1'" style="width: 25%;height: 125px;float: left;text-align: center;">
              <a class="imgforcat" href="#" ng-class="{'active': filterBusinessType == btypes.name}" ng-click="selectChangeBusinessType($event, btypes)" style="text-decoration: none;color: #333333;"><img height="350" width="400">{{btypes.name}}</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) says :

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

In your case, when your write `.imgforcat img:nth-child(n)` in your css, you try to match img siblings tags inside `.imgforcat`, which means something like that :

```
<div class="imgforcat">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

you should try to match your parent, then use `:nth-child` on `.imgforcat` (I'm supposing that all your imgforcat are siblings and child of the same parent `.parent`

```
.parent .imgforcat:nth-child(1) img {}
.parent .imgforcat:nth-child(2) img {}
...
```